# How to turn 3D points into fuzzy spheres, without changing their values? (Gaussian filter?)

Tags: normal-distribution, 3d, python

Basically, I have a bunch of sparse points in 3D space. I want to turn these points into fuzzy spheres. **I want the center of each fuzzy sphere to be the original point value**, and I want it to have a smooth falloff. Applying a Gaussian filter to my data gets me halfway there - I get fuzzy spheres. But now the values are much less than they were originally.

Is a Gaussian filter the right way to go about this? I'm doing this programmatically (Python). Can I apply a Gaussian filter([scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.gaussian_filter.html)) and then **multiply the result by `sqrt(2*pi * sigma^2)`** to get my original values back? Or am I way off?

Comment: What do you mean the values are wrong? In my view you have a delta function at each point that you smear out with a Gaussian. You can get the original points by placing a delta function at their means.

Comment: duplicated here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2397073/how-to-apply-a-3d-gaussian-filter-with-a-kernel-that-peaks-at-1

Comment: You start with sparse weighted points in 3D. You can't have the center of the sphere being the original weight if some spheres overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you may have misunderstood the Gaussian filter function. It originates from the image processing library and thus it will produce (i believe) this effect:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur

It sounds more like you are trying to do a Kernel Density Estimation (a Gaussian blur can be seen as a KDE):
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation

I.e. given a number $N$ of points $\mathbf{p}$, they create a density function

$$
\rho(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^N \delta(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{p}_i)
$$

the KDE version of this density function is is the sum of a set of "fuzzy sphere functions" (tri-variate Gaussian) $G_{\mathbf{p}_i}$ centered on each point, i.e.

$$
\eta(\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^N G_{\mathbf{p}_i}(\mathbf{x})
$$

Comment: which is the same as a Gaussian filtering. KDE does something else : given $\sum_i w_i \delta(x-p_i)$ compute $\sum_i \frac{w_i}{D(x)} G(a_i(x-p_i))$ where $D(x) =\sum_i G(a_i(x-p_i))$ (the local density of points) and $a_i$ can be constant or not.

Comment: Yhea like i said, but usually if you work with image oriented libraries but are actually doing work on probability functions or some other field it might not turn out like you want it to, witch is why its better to either find a library witch you understand or write the functions yourself or at lest be in sync with what your trying to accomplish (witch line of work was not stated in the question so its hard to be more specific, so i didn't bother with the normalizing explicitly :P )